# What is the meaning of Tamil saying "Begin with Ganesa and end up with Anjaneya"

Tags: hanuman, ganesha

[Wiki page on Panchmukhi Hanuman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panchamukha) says that there is Tamil saying "Begin with Ganesa and end up with Anjaneya". Can someone please explain what is the meaning of this?

Comment: Can you explain that in Tamil words correctly?  Normally Tamil transalations aren't proper because changing 1 letter changes meaning

Comment: @AkshayKumarS I wish to know the same. I tried google but no luck.

Comment: I hate this English translations of Tamil because each letter of Tamil has its own meaning!